# Trap ctrl-c, run a function, but don't exit subprocess?

Tags: bash, scala

It's actually a Scala REPL launched as a child process from a bash script.

I want to change what ctrl-c does, but otherwise not interfere with the scala REPL.

```
function ctrl_c_handler() {
  # do some stuff, but don't exit
}

trap ctrl_c_handler SIGINT

scala
```

Interestingly ignoring the signal works fine `trap '' SIGINT`. ctrl-c can't kill my REPL, but if I actually attach a function I haven't been able to prevent the process from exiting.

What are the options? The scala REPL needs to be in the foreground. It would be ok for the ctrl_c_handler to launch a background process.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, unless there's some really clever "jump back to where I was in the script before the ^C" set of commands that you could put at the end of `ctrl_c_handler()`.

Comment: Not sure if this is the exact issue, but I found a solution to my probleme here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146756/forward-sigterm-to-child-in-bash/146770

Answer (score 3):

Bash will see neither terminal input nor signals generated by the terminal (such as SIGINT) once the subprocess is started, because the subprocess becomes the only member of the terminal's foreground process group. Bash only sees the terminal again once the subprocess terminates.

Ignoring SIGINT in bash works because subprocesses inherit the dispositions of signals which have not been assigned signal handlers.

You could reassign SIGINT to a different keyboard symbol (or to no keyboard symbol) using `stty`; the subprocess will inherit that setting, too. That will cause ctrl-C to become an ordinary character so it won't interrupt the subprocess. Unfortunately, it won't interrupt bash either, so that's not really a solution.

You can create a subprocess over which you exert more control by creating a pseudoterminal (pty) and attaching the subprocess to the slave end of the pseudo-tty. Then you can pass input you read from the terminal to the subprocess by writing the data to the master end of the pty, and pass output from the subprocess back to the terminal by reading from the master end and writing to the terminal. In this configuration, you can trap SIGINT in the master process and not pass it through to the subprocess. However, you would almost certainly need to write this in some language (not necessarily C) which gives you access to system facilities; it might be possible in bash, but it would be quite a hack. Read `man pty` for a lot more information on where to start.

Comment: Makes sense. I looked for ways of monkey patching the REPL from within, but it got dark really quick. Customizing the REPL itself is pretty much off the table (it's actually a spark shell and therefore turtles all the way down). It sounds like explicitly putting a layer which selectively forwards input to the REPL process is the best lead. I'll check out pty.